# Script PHP to listener mysql inserts

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, websocket, listener

I have a Python bot inserting messages on MySQL, and i need to create a web page to show the messages, this page will be used by about 10 thousand users, i can't use requests.

I need to create script php to listener mysql inserts, every new insert, show in PHP Page(without reload page or something else). I created using Ajax, sending requests every 2 seconds, but, my mysql host have limits per hour, i need to create other solution, like a websocket/mysql listener. Without requests.

What is the best solution for me to create?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "can't use requests"?

Comment: Do you have thousands of users sitting there with a web page that is growing as data arrives?  Or are you describing something different?

Comment: I have a page that sends a request every 2 seconds, with too many users, this would result in the page going down.

Answer (score 1):

Several concerns here:

1. MySQL do not have a way for you to subscribe to database changes.
2. PHP do not have a central daemon to publish events to multiple visitors at once.

This risk having every PHP session to poll MySQL database for changes.

I guess a better design would be:

- Use a Redis for pubsub to signal any database change
- Have your Python bot to publish a signal either directly through dedicated PHP "publishing endpoint".
- All client may use [Server-sent Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) to listen to a PHP "subscriber endpoint", that would listen to the Redis pubsub internally.
- When the bot signals the publishing PHP, the publishing endpoint would query the MySQL database and publish the structured output to Redis.
- The "subscriber endpoint", listening to Redis pubsub, would then get what the "publishing endpoint" produced and send to the listening browsers.
- Browser receiving the SSE can update the browser according to the event data received.

```
Python Bot -> MySQL
           -> Publishing Endpoint -> Redis -> Subscriber Endpoint -> Browser
```

A even cleaner design would have the Python Bot to only send data to the "publishing endpoint". And have the "publishing endpoint" to deal both with MySQL storage and pubsub operations:

```
Python Bot -> Publishing Endpoint -> MySQL
                                  -> Redis -> Subscriber Endpoint -> Browser
```

Please note that this sort of near realtime communication would always need lots of concurrent connections. 10,000 concurrent users would mean 10,000 concurrent connections to your server.

Redis pubsub should be fine with this scale. But I guess you need multiple PHP-FPM + Nginx server to deal with the loads. Horizontal scaling is the key.